# For QuestaSim, what's the difference between vsim.exe and vsimk.exe?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, hdl, modelsim, questasim

For QuestaSim, what's the difference between vsim.exe and vsimk.exe under C:\questasim64_2020.4\win64\vsimk.exe?

for some reason, in order to invoke QuestaSim in batch mode from the Powershell prompt, some Windows computers require me to use vsimk.exe instead vsim.exe. Example:

```
PS> vsim.exe -c 
#hangs on some computers
```

versus:

```
PS> vsimk.exe -c 
#works on all computers
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

`vsimk.exe` is the core simulation engine. `vsim.exe` is a wrapper that set up a lot of things and allows you to run more complex tcl commands an d the GUI.

You should only be using `vsim.exe` The problems you see might be caused by Windows crashes, or running multiple version on the same machine. The Windows registry needs to be cleaned up. Look for a `ModelSim` entry and delete that.